# Will activity info transfer if I move repos from Gitlab to Github?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Even though this sounds trivial I couldn't find any valid answers.
My scenario is this. I work on many personal projects and I have used Gitlab as my git provider. But I want to move some of my repos from GitLab(private repos) and make them as public repos on Github. My question is:

1. If I move a repo from Gitlab to Github and the repo has contributions(in my case about 50 commits over a period of 2 years), will the Github activity graph also reflect the previous two years of commits and other activity which had happened on Gitlab?
2. In future is there a way to sync the commits between the two repos on Github and Gitlab?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: it's simple, create a github repo, add the git url as a remote, push and see what happens. writing this answer actually takes longer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that Github's activity graph is calculated from the actual commit dates in the repository, so the answer to your first question is yes.

I observed this myself, when I didn't push to Github for a few days, but made local commits.
After I finally pushed everything, the changes in my activity graph were at the days when I actually made the commits, not at the day when I pushed everything.

Plus, some time ago (maybe a year?), manipulating GitHub's activity graph was all the rage.
Suddenly everyone was writing scripts to create a new repository with dummy commits in the past, with the commit dates set in a manner so the GitHub activity graph would show some text *([some](https://github.com/public-contributions/HACK) [examples](https://github.com/nikhilweee/github-activity-art) [here](https://github.com/gelstudios/gitfiti))*.
This wouldn't be possible if GitHub would only consider pushs for creating this graph.